# How to use Widgets from bsi-software?

Tags: java, widget, eclipse-scout

I am currently working with Eclipse Scout 23.2.15 and I am looking for a way to replace the class ContentAssistFieldTable<...> as this class has been removed in an outdated version.
So I am looking for a way to display multiple information in a SmartField in a table.
That's why I wanted to use the widgets from bsi-software to solve this and I also found a page where different widgets are shown, but my problem is, I don't know how to use them now, especially the TableSmartField, which reflects exactly the function I need.

Can someone explain to me how to do this? Do I just have to include a dependency in the pom.xml, or do I have to include something in node_modules?
Or do I have to create it myself by creating a kind of template class?

[scout.bsi-software.com/jswidgets/#tablesmartfield](https://scout.bsi-software.com/jswidgets/#tablesmartfield)

Greetings Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution myself.
Instead of the ContentAssistFieldTable<...> class, you can simply use the getConfiguredColumnDescriptors method in SmartField.
It would look like this:

```java
@Override
protected ColumnDescriptor[] getConfiguredColumnDescriptors() {
    return new ColumnDescriptor[] {
        new ColumnDescriptor(MyOwnLookupCall.MyOwnTableRowData.item1, TEXTS.get("Item1"), 100),
        new ColumnDescriptor(MyOwnLookupCall.MyOwnTableRowData.item2, TEXTS.get("item2"), 100),
        new ColumnDescriptor(MyOwnLookupCall.MyOwnTableRowData.item3, TEXTS.get("item3"), 100),
    };
}
```